# How to convert when insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert some data to my database but I get an error

This is table schema

```
ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NAME varchar(100) NULL,
TYPEID  int NULL,
ISACTIVE bit NOT NULL,
CREATEDDATE datetime NULL,
CREATEDBY bigint NULL,
MODIFIEDDATE datetime NULL,
MODIFIEDBY bigint NULL
```

And this is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO SIZES 
VALUES     
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 'S001'), 'S', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S002' ), 'M', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S003' ), 'L', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S004' ), 'XL', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S005' ), '36', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S006' ), '37', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1'),
   (CONVERT(VARCHAR (20), 'S007' ), '38', '1', '01/12/2013', '1', '01/12/2013', '1')
```

And at the time the query runs into an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'S' to data type int.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL CAPS IN YOUR TITLES

Comment: It is not necessary to SHOUT your questions here. We can all read quite well. It won't get you an answer any faster, it's harder to read, and it's quite annoying to people. Please don't do that any longer. The Shift key is on your keyboard (twice) for a reason - properly cased text is easier to read and understand. Please use it.

Comment: First: why do you think you need to do a `CONVERT` on `S001` ?? That already **IS** a varchar! Also: if you insert values into an `INT` or `BIGINT` column, you should use just numerical literals like `1` - don't spell the out as a string (by using `'1'`). Same goes for `BIT` values - just use `0` or `1` - no need to put these into quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second declare type is

`TYPEID  int NULL`

so change it in varchar or nvarchar to insert varchar value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify fields you're inserting to:

```
INSERT INTO SIZES (NAME, TYPEID, ISACTIVE, CREATEDDATE, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDDATE, MODIFIEDBY)
VALUES (.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert VARCHAR 'S' into TYPEID INT column. Use following format and specify the column names that correspond to values:

```
INSERT INTO SIZES (NAME, TYPEID, ISACTIVE, CREATEDDATE, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDDATE, MODIFIEDBY)
VALUES (CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'S001'),'S','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S002' ),'M','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S003' ),'L','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S004' ),'XL','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S005' ),'36','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S006' ),'37','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S007' ),'38','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have declared Typeid as int but you are trying to insert S as varchar..
so change `Typeid as Varchar`

```
ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NAME varchar(100) Varchar,
TYPEID  Varchar(10) NULL,
ISACTIVE bit NOT NULL,
CREATEDDATE datetime NULL,
CREATEDBY bigint NULL,
MODIFIEDDATE datetime NULL,
MODIFIEDBY bigint NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert varchar values to int datatype. So, changing your database schema **TYPEID**(currently `int`) to `nvarchar(20)` or whatever size you want should solve your issue.

**TABLE SCHEMA:**

```
create table SIZES
(
ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
NAME varchar(100) NULL,
TYPEID  nvarchar(20) NULL,
ISACTIVE bit NOT NULL,
CREATEDDATE datetime NULL,
CREATEDBY bigint NULL,
MODIFIEDDATE datetime NULL,
MODIFIEDBY bigint NULL
)
```

**INSERT STATEMENT:**

```
INSERT INTO SIZES 
(NAME, TYPEID, ISACTIVE, CREATEDDATE, CREATEDBY, MODIFIEDDATE, MODIFIEDBY) VALUES 
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'S001'),'S','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S002' ),'M','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S003' ),'L','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S004' ),'XL','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S005' ),'36','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S006' ),'37','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1'),
(CONVERT(VARCHAR (20),'S007' ),'38','1','01/12/2013','1','01/12/2013','1')
```

Hope it helps you!!